# Jenssegers Blade Template Engine - page render error

Tags: template-engine, laravel-blade

I have views folder and my pages in views folder ( ex : home.blade.php,
test.blade.php) , I want to do page orientation but I have some error :

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Jenssegers\Blade\Blade;

$page= isset($_GET['p']) ? $_GET['p'] : 'home';

$blade = new Blade('views', 'cache');

echo $blade->make('home');

$pages = array('home' =>["views" => 'home.blade.php'],
               'test' =>["views" => 'test.blade.php']);

echo array_key_exists($page,$pages) ? $blade->render($pages[$page]
['views']) : $blade-> render('404.blade.php');
?>
```

Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: View [home.blade.php]
>   not found. in
>   /var/www/html/vendor/illuminate/view/FileViewFinder.php:137  Stack
>   trace: 
>   #0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your views name `home.blade.php` to `home`. Otherwise it considers it as directory hierarchy `home`->`blade`->`php`. In other words it's searching for a file with name `php.blade.php`, `php.php` or `php.css` under `home/blade/` directory.

```
$pages = array('home' =>["views" => 'home'],
               'test' =>["views" => 'test']);
```

Comment: I can' t do this in folder but ı do in larevel folder. But still ı have same error. I have views folder and views folder have home.blade.php and test.blade.php ?